# Unable to insert a record (SqlServer) using Subsonic 2.2

Tags: .net, subsonic2.2

I use SqlServer 2008. Here is the DB schema: (Please note that this only to test SubSonic)

```
Create Table Dept
(
 DeptID int not null Identity(1,1) primary key,
 DeptName varchar(20),
 Location varchar(30) 
) 

GO

 Create Table tUsers
 (
 UserID int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
 UserName varchar(50)
 )
 GO

create table Emp
(
 EmpID int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
 DeptID int foreign key references dept(deptid),
 CreatedBy varchar(50),
 EmpName varchar(50)
 )
```

Here is the C# code to save an employee:

```
Emp em = new Emp();            
em.DeptID = 3;
em.CreatedBy = "Temp1";
em.EmpName = "Temp3";            
em.Save();
```

And here is the Sql profiler trace:

```
exec sp_executesql N'/* GetInsertSql(Emp) */ INSERT INTO [dbo].[Emp]([DeptID],[CreatedBy],[EmpName]) VALUES(@DeptID,@CreatedBy,@EmpName);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS newID;',N'@DeptID int,@CreatedBy varchar(8000),@EmpName varchar(5)',@DeptID=3,@CreatedBy='',@EmpName='Temp3'
```

As can be seen, CreatedBy is always empty, even though value is passed from application. (Earlier, this column was a foreign key, but SubSonic always threw (Format) error and hence I changed this to varchar, based on a suggestion from SubSonic Forum).

Any idea what went wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Sathya Narayanan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreatedBy` is part of SubSonic's automatic audit fields. Columns named

- CreatedBy
- CreatedOn
- ModifiedBy
- ModifiedOn

are filled in automatically with the value of `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` and `DateTime.Now`.

That's also why you kept getting the format error.

I recommend to simply rename this column to not have kick in the audit mecanism.

See also http://jamesewelch.wordpress.com/2008/09/24/how-to-use-custom-audit-fields-with-subsonic/